# Clone div and change values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When pressing a button I want to make a new copy of the `<div class="search-result">` and change the h3 inside it.

I tried to clone it but that would only clone the already consisting one and I don't know how to change the value of h3 in the new cloned one. 
as in `$(".search-result").clone().appendTo(".search");` How do I change the value of the one I just cloned, since I have a loop to make more of these?

Is there another method to do this?

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 search" style="background-color: blue;">
                        <h2>Sök resultat</h2>
                        <div class="search-result">
                            <h3>Titel(year)</h3>
                            <input id="btnFavorite" type="submit" value="Favoritfilm" class="btn btn-warning">
                            <input id="btnArkiv" type="submit" value="Arkiv" class="btn btn-warning">
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/find/#find-selector, http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2

Comment: $(".search-result").clone().appendTo(".search").find('h3').text('new value')

Comment: This works partly, Since I want to copy lets 20 times, first it will copy the first one like it should, second time of the loop it will copy the first and the copy one. This means it copies all existing divs with .search-result, whic last iteration would mean 20->copy all those -> and add them

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. In this example you first need to clone the node using `cloneNode` then append it to the parent div.
Find the h3 tag inside the cloned div using `find()`and use `html()` to manipulate the inner html of h3 tag.

```
            can = document.getElementById(".search_result")
            clone = can.cloneNode(".search_result");
            document.getElementById(".search").appendChild(clone);
            clone.find('h3').html( 'put new value here' );
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: I'm reviewing the answer.